# HDMI No signal on one tv but signal fine on another

Tags: hdmi, pi-zero-w, signal

I am using a pi zero w. I have used it on two TV's to date. It's been a month or so since I last used it and now it works on only one of the TV's.

This wouldn't be a problem but I am giving this to someone as a gift and I need to know it will work on any TV I plug it into. I am using the same PSU (official raspberry pi psu), HDMI cable, mini HDMI to HDMI adapter, SD card... everything is the same as when it did work last month, and everything is the same when I test it today on both my TV's. My attempts to fix have been adjusting the config.txt with the following:

1

```
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
hdmi_drive=2
```

2

`config_hdmi_boost=4` & then `config_hdmi_boost=8`

3

```
hdmi_safe=1
```

The really annoying part is that it worked fine on both TV's and the last time I used it before today was on the TV that it no longer works on. Having verified it still works fine on the other one I am now left wondering why it chooses not to work on this one now, and what else I can possibly try?

Comment: I'm betting something's wrong with the other TV. Try plugging some other HDMI input to it, and make sure it works.

Comment: The other TV has both HDMI's connected up to things on a daily basis and works fine. I've just tried it on two screens at work. 1 behaved the same - giving no signal. The other displayed the pi but the pi rebooted a few times initially and the screen was flashing every few seconds as though I just turned the channel to HDMI

Comment: I got in touch with the supplier and they have an open returns policy. As such I am returning this and getting a replacement. They will be testing it, so if I find out what the issue is I will update this, else should this post be closed?